# Dynamically add and delete two EditText and save information in them

Tags: android

I want to dynamically create two editText fields side by side, store information in them and delete whenever I need to.
Right now i have static fields, so it looks like this
[image]

Left ones have id siteName1, siteName2... right ones have id siteURL1, siteURL2... Also I have two buttons - Save and Load.

```
prefsEditor.putString("siteName1_txt", siteName1.getText().toString());
prefsEditor.putString("siteURL1_txt", siteURL1.getText().toString());
```

and so on...

```
siteName1.setText(myPrefs.getString("siteName1_txt", "").toString());
siteURL1.setText(myPrefs.getString("siteURL1_txt", "").toString());
```

and so on...
My app is voice controlled, so when I say command, it checks if I have right website name and opens it.

```
if (commandList.contains(siteNames[i].getText().toString())) {
                    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www." + siteURLs[i].getText().toString());
                    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
```

Website names nad URLs are put to strings. So my question is - can I add two editTexts and delete them dynamically. Can I save information in them, so when I close and open app - info is saved. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I guess you can use the View.setVisibility(VISIBLE) & View.setVisibility(GONE) to avoid loosing info and hiding the views.

Comment: use arraylist of customobjects